# How to return array from class function

Tags: php, function, class, oop

I want to return an array from function but it return nothing. If i declare any string that return fines but i need to return.

```
class someclasss {

  function somefunction {

    $arr = array();

    if(condition){
      array_push($arr, array("name"=>"john"));
      return $arr;
    }

  }

}
```

I tried to return an simple array also but that also didnt worked!

Can anyone help to know how to return an array from function??

Answer (score 1):

Your current code has two problems:

1. It is not returning the variable that contains the array. It is returning the result of the array_push() function, which is probably not what you want.
2. It is only calling return when *inside* the conditional. If the conditional doesn't fire, no return statement is encountered. This essentially is equivalent to doing `return null;` if the condition doesn't fire.

You probably want something more like:

```
function somefunction {
  $arr = array();
  if(condition){
    array_push($arr, array("name"=>"john"));
  }
  return $arr;
}
```

Which can be short-cutted to:

```
function somefunction {
  return condition ? ['name' => 'john'] : [];
}
```

Comment: if i return a string inside if statement, it works! than why not array?

Comment: Returning arrays works fine, but `$var` is *not* an array. See the docs for `array_push()` -- it doesn't return the new array.

Comment: Yes! you are right but its also not returning $arr!

Comment: Move `return $arr;` so that it's *outside* the conditional.

Comment: yeah! its quite simple, dont know why not working at my side, will check it, thx

Comment: if found the problem, i am using this condition - "if ($tmpFilePath != "")", its not passing files with extension .exe, can you please tell what could be the reason, png, jpg,etc.. are working